# How to make Data access to the users? When both servers are down in MIRRORING

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

WHAT ARE THE SOLUTIONS FOR THESE THREE CASES USING "MIRRORING CONCEPT"

```
Server A=PRINCIPLE OR PRIMARY,
Server B=MIRROR,
Server C=WITNESS
```

1)what if Server A and Server B are completely down,

2)what if Server B and Server C are completely down,

3)what if Server A and Server C are completely down

How to make Data access to the users?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? A homework question?

Comment: Yeah. Seems the poster considers reading the documentation not acceptable. "Always On" is not exactly a totally new feature. The fact that this is new in 2012 hints that the only answer here, for an outdated version of sql server, is "programming".

Comment: @ CL  yeah.its a little bit a home work type of question please suggest me the answers for both synchronous and asynchronous modes

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at the following article which will explain all about database mirroring concepts:

[Database Mirroring Concepts - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934127%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)